# What's the easiest way to get insights on github PR review activity across a repository?

Tags: github

I'd like information, similar to what is provided on the insights tab for commits, but for code review activity.  In particular, either

- the number of Pull request review comments over time
- the number of specific (say lgtm) comments given
- the number of lines of code (and maybe number of files) that were reviewed as well